# prevent MediaRequestProtection errors in Coveo lists

Tags: coveo, mediaurls

We have Coveo list pages(using Javascript framework) and there are MediaRequestProtection errors for the media results.
`***ERROR MediaRequestProtection: An invalid/missing hash value was encountered. The expected hash value: X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0X0XX0. Media URL:***`

On non coveo pages, we used `Sitecore.Resources.Media.HashingUtils.ProtectAssetUrl(MediaUrl)` which is hashing the mediaUrl and no errors are reported from these.

So how should we hash the media url's from Coveo Lists? Thanks in advance for any ideas/advice.

Comment: Any Ideas please?